# Remove "Edit Link" next to "Publish immediatley" when adding a new post

Tags: scheduled-posts

I need to remove the **Edit link** next to **Publish immediately** as I don't want my user to schedule the post.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you found in [your research](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bbutton+%2Bpublish+is%3Aanswer)?

Comment: Nothing! That's the reason for posting here...

Comment: I did not see the link... sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea to hide the *Edit* link via CSS:

```
function wpse85434_hide_editlinks() {
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
        // only for non-admins
        echo "<style>.misc-pub-section .edit-timestamp{display:none !important;} </style>";
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php','wpse85434_hide_editlinks');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php','wpse85434_hide_editlinks');
```

I use `!current_user_can('manage_options')` so it will be visible for the admin.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Make sure this only prints in the correct screen, e.g.: `add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'callback');`.

Comment: Birgire, it works like a charm!
Thanks brasofilo too!

Comment: ok great. Thanks brasofilo, I updated the code example with your suggestion.